# Choosing the correct collection

Tags: java, collections

I'm designing a system which needs a specific collection, it is written in Java. I need to store the history of prices of stock (dates and time).

One stock can have multiple dates and times as I want to show the previous prices.

Which collection would I use to map a stock id to multiple dates AND times?

I know there are HashTables, but I can't see how they will work as they still take only a key and a value. I have a stock class, within it I want a collection which takes and a value and a value.

Comment: You need to store the information in memory (RAM)? Or do you want to persit it in some kind of database? Just storing the information in memory will fail sooner or later due to memory requirements (assuming infinite amount of memory is not available).

Comment: Good question but thats out of scope of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be using google guava multi-map (If you are ok to include third party jars).

multi-map allows you to add elements with same key.

Here is [simple tutorial](http://tomjefferys.blogspot.com/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html).

**EDIT:**

If not allowed to use guava, then another option would be:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Stock>> map = HashMap<String, ArrayList<Stock>>()
```

Here `Stock` is simple POJO class with timeStamp and stock symbol.

Comment: Thanks but no third party jars! Didn't know they existed until now but they definitely won't be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a `Price` object, then you can use a map like this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Price>> map = HashMap<String, ArrayList<Price>>();
```

Of course you can change your key type to your own.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a map of the stock IDs as the key, and a list of prices as the value.

```
Map<Integer, List<Price>> stocks = new HashMap<Integer, List<Price>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashMap where key will be stockid and value will be arraylist of the objects which contain date and time.

`Map<Integer, ArrayList<Price>> anyname = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Price>>();`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hashtable containing another type of collection. For example, if your stock IDs are Integers and being able to see the history of prices chronologically is your main use case, create a hashtable of arraylists, and keep the arraylists sorted by date:

```
HashMap< Integer, ArrayList<Stock> > stockCollection = new HashMap< Integer, ArrayList<Stock> >();
```

Or, if you really need to be able to access the stock price for a particular date in O(1) time, create a hashtable of hashtables:

```
HashMap< Integer, HashMap<Date, Stock> > stockCollection = new HashMap< Integer, HashMap<Date, Integer> >();
```